# How can I use my wand/offhand instead of my signature spell?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a mouse button to a regular attack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63413/how-do-i-set-a-mouse-button-to-a-regular-attack)

I am equipped with a wand with magic abilities, and want to switch to it when monsters resist to my primary or secondary ability.

As far as I could observer, this happens only when my spirit level drops to a level insufficient for me to use my secondary.

How do I use my wand *directly*?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How do I set a mouse button to a regular attack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63413/21177)

Comment: Right on, @Sean. Time to close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a "fast switch" to auto attack for the same reason [you can't switch to another skill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66851/23609): you're supposed to plan carefully your game style, and manage accordingly your resources.

Anyway there's [a whole thread in the official forum](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5141954178?page=3) dedicated to the auto-attack question, and the general consensus is that you should never get to the point where you have to use your auto-attack, especially as a caster. You should always have a skill ready to use, even if the monsters resist your primary or secondary.

Comment: That's as it may be, but I'd like to see my choices first, even if I myself would come to the same conclusion ;)
Regardless thereof, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Elective mode. Options, gameplay, elective mode. and from there you can set anything to any hotkey. Thank me later